# Electron, The window belongs to tray. I don’t want it to be showed in the dock bar

Tags: electron

In macOS, right click on the icon in the dock bar, all current windows will be showed and allowed to switch. But I only want to show a window, how to configure it? The other window belongs to tray. I don’t want it to be showed in the dock bar.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting `skipTaskbar` to true for that window ?

> skipTaskbar Boolean (optional) - Whether to show the window in taskbar. Default is false.

Also you can use [setSkipTaskbar](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-window#winsetskiptaskbarskip) function to hide it at run time.

*PS*: I didn't try it, but based on your description, this might help you.

Comment: ```javascript
this.window.setSkipTaskbar(false)
```
I tried setting up the setSkipTaskbar, but it didn't have the desired effect

Comment: You need to put it on your browserWindow object  http://electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-window not the in the window object